# Is it possible to add/create custom enviroments from HDRI files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have running Autodesk Forge Viewer and I was wondering if there is a know feature to add custom Lighting and Environments from an HDRI file since I was unable to find any helpful information in the Documentation. Does the Viewer support this feature or how would one go about adding a custom environment.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the environment maps is not an officially supported feature, but it *can* be done with a bit of hacking. The viewer uses DDS files for environment maps. Check out https://github.com/wallabyway/adding-shadows#sharper-ibl-reflections-image-based-light-ie-skybox for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it did not really help. There is no real tutorial or code on how to add the .DDS files. Do I add them to the model files themselves before I upload them to Forge Model Derivative or do I load them to the Viewer afterwards. Is the second option even possible? Does it work only for Fusion files?